# JUnit parameterized test for median function

Tags: java, junit

I am trying to write a JUnit test for a function that finds the median for a given array of `double` elements.

However, I am struggling with passing the parameters. My code looks like this:

```
@RunWith(Parameterized.class)
public class MedianParameterizedTest extends TestCase {


    private Double[] numbers;
    private Double expectedMedian;

    public MedianParameterizedTest(Double[] numbers, double expectedMedian){
        this.numbers = numbers;
        this.expectedMedian = expectedMedian;
    }

    @Parameterized.Parameters
    public static Collection medianArrays() {
        return Arrays.asList(new Object[][] {
                { {-5.0,-4.0,3.0},  -4.0}
        });
    }

    @Test
    public void test1() {
        //doing test
    }
}
```

But this gives me an  illegal initializer for java.lang.Object error for the medianArrays collection and I can't find out why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create the first (array) argument for each test using `new Double[]`.

You have three levels of nested arrays in your code:

- the top level is the entire collection, with one element per test case,
- the next level down contains the two parameters for each test case,
- the innermost level, within the first argument for each test case, contains all of the numbers that you wish to calculate the median on in one test case.

After `new Object[][]`, Java knows that two levels of nested arrays are to be expected. After `new Object[][] {`, it still knows that there is one more level of array to expect, but after `new Object[][] { {`, it's not expecting any more further levels of nested array. If you want to create an array at this point you must specify the type.

Try the following instead:

```java
    @Parameterized.Parameters
    public static Collection medianArrays() {
        return Arrays.asList(new Object[][] {
                { new Double[] {-5.0,-4.0,3.0},  -4.0}
        });
    }
```